# Overriding a publically aliased method via private inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, c++17, private-inheritance

I have a class heirarchy where there is one base type `Base` with a list of implementations and another base class, `AnotherBase`, that is almost like `Base` but a little different. To express this in the language I used private inheritance on the second base class (so there is no as-is relationship between implementations of the latter with the former).

Let's say this is the code (https://wandbox.org/permlink/2e2EG0eKmcLiyvgt)

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Impl : public Base {
public:
    void foo() {
        cout << "Impl::foo()" << endl;
    }
};

class AnotherBase : private Base {
public:
    using Base::foo;

    // other virtual methods
};

class Derived : public AnotherBase {
public:
    explicit Derived(std::unique_ptr<Base> base) : base_{std::move(base)} {}

    void foo() override {
        base_->foo();
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Base> base_;
};

int main() {
    auto impl = std::make_unique<Impl>();
    std::make_unique<Derived>(std::move(impl))->foo();
}
```

When I try to compile the above code, I get the following error

```
prog.cc:27:38: error: 'Base' is a private member of 'Base'
```

What is the best way to express the above idea if this does not work? Also why does it not work?

Comment: Which line is 27?

Comment: @cdhowie if you follow the link it should have the entire program with the line as well

Comment: @cigien sorry I’m not sure i follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On these two lines within the declaration of `Derived`, `Base` is resolved as the the privately-inherited `Base` type since it is in scope -- even though it is private:

```
explicit Derived(std::unique_ptr<Base> base) : base_{std::move(base)} {}
// ...
std::unique_ptr<Base> base_;
```

C++ does not ignore in-scope names that refer to things the current scope doesn't have access to.  It seems logical that the compiler would look in an outer scope for a `Base` that it *does* have access to, but this is not what happens.  The compiler simply stops at the closest `Base` it sees without regard for any access modifiers.

This can be trivially fixed by referring to the `Base` type through the top-level namespace prefix `::`:

```
explicit Derived(std::unique_ptr<::Base> base) : base_{std::move(base)} {}
// ...
std::unique_ptr<::Base> base_;
```

Both refer to the same type, but `Derived` does not have access to the inherited `Base` name, while it does have access to the global `Base` name.

You could also fix this issue by redefining what `Base` means within `Derived`. At the top of the `Derived` declaration, you can add:

```
protected:
    using Base = ::Base;
```

This hides the inherited `Base` name behind a type alias that `Derived` does have access to.